# Django: Django-Rest-Framework gives Attribution error (pagination)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create migrations of a project which uses [Rest Framework pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/).

But I'm getting error as `Attribution error: 'module' object has no attribute BasePaginationSerializer`. I have tried uninstalling-resinstalling the said versions of Python, Django and RestFramework. But I still get that error.

Here's the screenshot of terminal showing error.

[image]

Here's a chunk of the code present in `paginator.py`

```
import urlparse

from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, Page, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from django.utils.http import urlencode

from rest_framework import serializers, pagination

class CustomPaginationSerializer(pagination.BasePaginationSerializer):#Here it shows the error.
    meta = MetaSerializer(source='*')
    results_field = 'objects'
```

Can someone help me out in getting this issue resolved?

Info: 
- Here's the project which I'm trying to build. https://github.com/mozilla/zamboni

- I'm using Ubuntu 15.10
- Python - 2.7.10
- Django - 1.8.7

Answer (score 2):

`Django Rest Framework` doesn't provide anything like `BasePaginationSerializer`, that's why you're getting an error - because it doesn't exist. You probably want to use `BasePagination`